# android fabric: crashlytics+answers

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm able to send custom events with answers along with crashreports with crashlytics.However Fabric plugin for android studio suggests me to add following dependency:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}
```

Do I need this dependency?

Comment: Obviously you want if you want crashlytics 
see here https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: This dependency is `Fabric Answers` related.I'm curious is it necessary dependency?It seems like everything working without it.

Comment: yep you have to add it anyway what is wrong in not adding it????

Comment: I'm trying to keep build size as low as posible :)

Answer (score 1):

By default when you enable Fabric, you get Answers along with it. So you don't need that extra answers dependency line.

Comment: Fabric's documentation is abysmal